# Lorentz Cone is not polyhedral cone.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Lorentz cone: $$L_{n+1} := \{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n+1})\in \Bbb R^{n+1} : x_1^2 - x_2^2-\cdots-x_{n+1}^2\geq 0, \text{and} \ x_1 \geq 0 \}$$

I have verified that Lorentz Cone is a full cone. But stuck with showing that it is not-polyhedral.

We know a cone is polyhedral if it can be written as intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces.

We have a hint: Since Lorentz Cone has infinitely many extreme rays so it is not polyhedral.

Can one please elaborate on that reason or give some other reason?

Thank You.

Comment: $\{(x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\ d^2\geq x_2^2+x_3^2+...+x_{n+1}^2\}$ is a closed ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How many extreme points does a sphere have? Look at the rays passing through extreme points of the ball (but include the ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ before drawing the ray) and the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: infinitely many..

Comment: A cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is polyhedral iff it is finitely generated. Since $L_n$ has infinitely many extreme rays...

Answer (score 0):

A polyhedral is formed by intersecting finitely many halfspace, hence it can only have finitely many extreme ray. A non-zero element of a cone is an extreme ray if there are $n-1$ linearly independent active constraint at $x$. An upper bound for the number of extreme ray if you have $m$ constraints would be $\binom{m}{n-1}$ , which is finite.

Hence if a cone has infinitely many extreme ray, it can't be a polyhedral.